# What happens if I cast disenchant in response to the triggered ability of animate dead?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

My opponent has [Griselbrand](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Griselbrand) in his graveyard and casts [Animate Dead](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Animate%20Dead).

It resolves, causing the triggered ability to go on the stack which would bring Griselbrand back to play. In response, I [Disenchant](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Disenchant) Animate Dead.

What happens?

My friend believes it would be the same as the bouncing [Oblivion Ring](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Oblivion%20Ring) trick-- the triggered ability would still activate, causing Griselbrand to come out, but the aura would be gone before its "leaving the battlefield" trigger has anything to target: i.e. Griselbrand comes out and stays out, while Animate Dead goes to the graveyard.

This sounds right. Is it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**If you destroy Animate Dead before the creature card it enchants returns to the battlefield, the creature card will remain in the graveyard and never enter the battlefield.**

Read the text of Animate Dead carefully:

> When Animate Dead enters the battlefield, **if it's on the battlefield,** it loses "enchant creature card in a graveyard" and gains "enchant creature put onto the battlefield with Animate Dead."

If Animate Dead enters the battlefield, it triggers its ETB ability. If someone responds with a Disenchant to destroy it, then by the time the ETB resolves, the aura will no longer be on the battlefield and the ability does nothing on resolving.

The Oblivion Ring trick you mentioned works only because its ETB ability does not have that condition.

Comment: I see now that it means *"When ~ enters the battlefield, and if it's still on the battlefield at the time this ability resolves..."* but holy shit is the chosen phrasing counter-intuitive.